# In Android, how do I sync audio recording with simultaneous playback?

Tags: android, audio, synchronization, media-player, mediarecorder

I'm trying to write a function that will record the users voice while an instrumental is playing in the background.

I have been fairly successful in getting 2 MediaPlayers to start at almost the exact same time. Using Threads and the CyclicBarrier, I have been able to start 2 MediaPlayer within 5 milliseconds of each, which sounds pretty good.

The problem is that whenever I attempt to start a MediaRecorder and a MediaPlayer at the same time, there is a noticeable delay between them. This is problematic, because when I playback the recorded audio and the instrumental, they are not in sync with each other because the recorded started at a different time than the player.

Here is the function and the 2 Threads that I'm trying to use for the Recorder and Player. I apologize for the length, but if anybody has any better ideas I would be very grateful:

```
private void onRecord(boolean start) {
    if (start) {
       final CyclicBarrier recordBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);
       final CyclicBarrier postrecordBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);
       Thread beatTask = new Thread(new RecordBeatPlayTask(recordBarrier, postrecordBarrier), "Thread 1");
       Thread recordTask = new Thread(new RecordVoiceRecordTask(recordBarrier, postrecordBarrier), "Thread 2");

       beatTask.start();
       recordTask.start();
    } 
    else {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecordBeatPlayer.stop();

            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
            mRecordBeatPlayer.release();
            mRecordBeatPlayer = null;
    }
}

private static class RecordVoiceRecordTask implements Runnable {

    private CyclicBarrier barrier;
    private CyclicBarrier barrier2;

    public RecordVoiceRecordTask(CyclicBarrier barrier, CyclicBarrier barrier2) {
        this.barrier = barrier;
        this.barrier2 = barrier2;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mRecorderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            mRecorderPath += "/HypeHopRecording.mp4";
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mRecorderPath);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Recorder failed", "prepare() failed");
            }
            barrier.await();
            mRecorder.start();
            barrier2.await();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has crossed the barrier");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RecordActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RecordActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

private static class RecordBeatPlayTask implements Runnable {

    private CyclicBarrier barrier;
    private CyclicBarrier barrier2;

    public RecordBeatPlayTask(CyclicBarrier barrier, CyclicBarrier barrier2) {
        this.barrier = barrier;
        this.barrier2 = barrier2;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            mRecordBeatPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                mRecordBeatPlayer.setDataSource(mBeatPath);
                mRecordBeatPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            barrier.await();
            mRecordBeatPlayer.start();
            barrier2.await();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has crossed the barrier");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RecordActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RecordActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! This is an old question... So did you came up to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

basically, there is deplay between 'mRecordBeatPlayer.start()' and user can hear the sound, you have to test out this deplay.